# Let $C$ and $C'$ be algebraic (smooth) curves.If morphism $φ:C→C'$ satisfies the condition that $＃φ^{-1}(Q)＝1$ for all $Q∈C'$, why $φ$ is isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ and $C'$ be algebraic (smooth) curves.
If morphism $φ:C→C'$ satisfies the condition that $＃φ^{-1}(Q)＝1$ for all $Q∈C'$, why $φ$ is isomorphism ?

If I could prove $φ$ is a degree one morephism, degree 1 morphism between smooth curves is isomorphism.Thus I want to prove $φ$ has degree 1, in other words, corresponding extension of function field has degree 1.

Comment: The degree is the cardihnality of the fibers for a generic point

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez not true! The *separable* degree is the cardinality of the fiber for a general point. See my answer for an explicit counterexample.

Comment: @HankScorpio you are right, I was thinking about Riemann surfaces

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Purely inseparable maps of curves give fibers of cardinality one but are not isomorphisms. In characteristic $p$, consider the map $\Bbb P^1\to \Bbb P^1$ by $[x:y]\mapsto [x^p:y^p]$ which on the standard affine opens is of the form $k[t]\to k[t]$ by $t\mapsto t^p$, and this [is a bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920224/).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that example. In characteristic $0$, the titled statement holds ?

Comment: @kleinfour yes, that's correct. In characteristic zero, all extensions are separable, so since the separable degree is the cardinality of a general fiber, a map of smooth curves which is bijective induces an isomorphism on function fields and therefore an isomorphism of those curves.